# Best way to salt-hash to database

Tags: php, sql, security, bcrypt, password-hash

I'm trying to improve my login system and make it more secure.

```
$hashed_pass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Is this function the best way to safely store password and other information in the database?

Comment: Yes, for passwords. What "other information"? If you need to be able to get the original data you need to encrypt, not hash. Also hopefully using parameterized queries.

Comment: The only winning move is not to play. Enable social sign-in (i.e. with google and/or facebook) and make password storage someone else's problem

Comment: @apokryfos Because that is entirely devoid of problems and will never ever fail or present any sort of inconvenience. ;-P

Comment: @deceze of course it can fail, but it probably isn't going to be your fault :P

Comment: @apokryfos thanks for the edit, you were "spot on" ;-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is this function the best way to safely store password and other information in the database?*

Yes it is safe to use. However, if you're looking for something even more powerful and your server supports it, you can use Argon2.

Reference links are:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php (it's listed with the syntax).

However, using a custom salt has been deprecated in PHP 7.0.0

> **Warning**
>   The salt option has been deprecated as of PHP 7.0.0. It is now preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: you're welcome @KyiKyi